# MySQL query all distinct from column A where none of them has a specific value in column B

Tags: mysql, sql

Could someone kindly point me to the right direction to seek further or give me any hints regarding the following task?

I'd like to list all the distinct values from a MySQL table from column A that don't have a specific value in column B. I mean none of the same A values have this specific value in B in any of there rows. Taking the following table (let this specific value be 1):

```
column A  | column B
----------------------
apple     |
apple     |
apple     | 1
banana    | anything
banana    |
lemon     |
lemon     | 1
orange    |
```

I'd like to get the following result:

```
banana
orange
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE A NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT A FROM MY_TABLE WHERE B = 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since there are null values, I have also added a nvl condition to column B .

**ORACLE:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_A  FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE COLUMN_A  NOT IN (SELECT COLUMN_A FROM MY_TABLE WHERE nvl(COLUMN_B,'dummy')  = '1');
```

**MYSQL:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_A  FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE COLUMN_A  NOT IN (SELECT COLUMN_A FROM MY_TABLE WHERE IFNULL(COLUMN_B,'dummy')  = '1');
```

Comment: I think columnA also print `apple and lemon`

Comment: @Sadikhasan. Yeah. I tried and then changed my query to second query. Since there are null values, I have also added a nvl condition to column B

Comment: @Jens. Refer my updated answer and the comment above.

Comment: @Jens: Please remove the downvote and consider upvoting since the second query gives output as the OP requested.

Comment: @NishanthiGrashia Please remove the first query.

Comment: I think `nvl` is oracle operator, mysql does not support it http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

Comment: @Uriil: Thank you. I have included the IFNULL function. Please edit if the syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM your_Table WHERE Column_A NOT IN(
    SELECT Column_A FROM Your_Table WHERE Column_B = '1'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This statement gives you the expected result:

```
select COLUMNA from myTable where COLUMNA not in (select distinct COLUMNA from myTable where columnB
=1) group by COLUMNA;
```